# Скролл до нужного места

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, прокрутка

Такой вот вопрос. да, не стандартный, но интересно, на что способен JS.
Вообщем есть код, чтобы при нажатии, опускался или поднимался до нужного места.
(нажимая на пункты). и вот в коде можно поставить время прокрутки, например "1" - мгновенно, а "500" - пол секунды. но проблема в том, что когда до блока 200-500px то это красиво смотрится, а если 3000-5000px, то "матрица какая то" пробегает.

Так вот, можно ли как то реализоваться, чтобы он до определённого блока высчитывал расстояния и от этого выбирал, 1\1000с или 500мс. то есть, если блок не далеко, то плавно к нему подойти, а если блок далеко, то мгновенно.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a[href*="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
  }, 500, 'linear');     //500мс
});
});
```

```css
.section {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
}
.nav__link {
  
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav" id="nav">
<a class="nav__link" href="#s1" data-scroll="">один</a>
<a class="nav__link" href="#s2" data-scroll="">два</a>
<a class="nav__link" href="#s3" data-scroll="">три</a>
<a class="nav__link" href="#s4" data-scroll="">четыре</a>
</nav>


<section class="section" id="s1">1111111</section>

<section class="section" id="s2">2222222</section>

<section class="section" id="s3">3333333</section>

<section class="section" id="s4">4444444</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a[href*="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  let anchor = $(this).attr('href'),
      anchorOffsetTop = $(anchor).offset().top,
      currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop(),
      scrollDistance = Math.abs(anchorOffsetTop - currentScroll),
      scrollSpeed = scrollDistance > 1200 ? 1 : 500

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: anchorOffsetTop
  }, scrollSpeed, 'linear');
});
});
```

```css
.section {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
}
.nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.nav__link {
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.nav__link:hover {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav" id="nav">
<a class="nav__link" href="#s1" data-scroll="">один</a>
<a class="nav__link" href="#s2" data-scroll="">два</a>
<a class="nav__link" href="#s3" data-scroll="">три</a>
<a class="nav__link" href="#s4" data-scroll="">четыре</a>
</nav>


<section class="section" id="s1">1111111</section>

<section class="section" id="s2">2222222</section>

<section class="section" id="s3">3333333</section>

<section class="section" id="s4">4444444</section>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Но это не много не то. Я хочу, чтобы если я на первом блоке (1111111), то до второго оно плавно, а до третьего мгновенно (в принципе как и у вас), но есть я на втором блоке, то до (3333333), оно должно плавно, так же как и до (11111111), но вот уже до (44444444) мгновенно...и так же есть на (4444444), до до первого мгновенно. Надёюсь правильно объяснил

Comment: Наверное это нужно делать как то через (offset и position), но я не знаю как это реализовать.

Comment: @ДимаСторчеус подкорректировал ответ